# Zend 1.11 automatically applies htmleneities filter on submit button

Tags: php, zend-framework, character-encoding, special-characters, zend-decorators

we render a German encoded string `&#252;bermitteln` from a file.

Problem:
zend form does not consider `&#252;` as a character and displays the same value on my submit button.

Quick fix we got:

```
html_entity_decode($form->submit->renderViewHelper())
```

However we have lot of forms and it is troublesome job to make changes everywhere.
So what is the proper way of achieving this.

Comment: `&#252;bermitteln` is a wrong term. It simply means "oversending" - why don't you use "send" or "Senden" just btw ...

Comment: I didn't get your comment...sorry...@cept0

Comment: allright now I got it...we have a system where user can enter there own translations...so u se...we don't have much control over there @cep0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZF escapes labels by default. This is a good thing. It's not that Zend Form "doesn't consider `&#252;` a character", it's that you are supply an already escaped string so the escaping is happening twice. (View source and you'll see `&amp;#252;`.)

You can either run the data you're reading in from the file through `html_entity_decode()` (preferred), or disabling escaping on the submit element's label decorator:

```
$form->submit->getDecorator('label')->setOption('escape', false);
```